# Sourcing PC parts for a hands-on workshop

Tags: hardware

I am trying to source for PC parts for a hands-on workshop. The goal is for students to learn how to assemble the main components of a PC into a desktop casing.
Due to the limited duration of the workshop (60 minutes) I am looking for parts that easily slot into a casing ... very much like a LEGO set.
Do you know of a place online I can purchase such a basic set of PC parts.
My alternative is to source regular PC parts but I was wondering if there is such a learning set out there for children.
Thank you.

Comment: How many do you need? And how old are the children?

Comment: check your local thrift shops for such parts